# Preserve Formatting in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I cannot seem to preserve previously set formatting upon adding a new column in a Power Query.

- Source table has values as percent with two decimals

[image]

- I import into PQ and it applies what it thinks is proper formatting:

[image]

- I change the formatting to what I want:

[image]

- Pivot on the Date Column

[image]

- Load it back to the worksheet

[image]

- Note that the percent formatting is lost.

If I format this "results" table in Excel as percent with two decimals, and subsequently add "rows" (eg, a new entry in the Source with the same date but a different value) and Refresh, the formatting will be preserved.

[image]

**But** if the new entry requires a **new column** (eg a new date), the formatting of this new column, when loaded back to Excel, will be `General` and not `Percentage`.

[image]

The Properties for the Query are as below.

[image]

Is there a PQ solution for these issues (both the initial and "refresh" formatting)?  Or must I resort to VBA with a Worksheet_change event?

Here is the `M-Code` for the Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Value", Percentage.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US")[Date]), "Date", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: So,  I know this is 3 years old, but I am having the exact same issue except with currency rather than percentages.  Is there a known solution or is still a VBA workaround?

Comment: @tormond I have not run across a solution, other than using a VBA event to do the Excel formatting.

Comment: Sad.  Thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the same behaviour. Values of type `Percentage` display as percentages within the Power Query Editor, but load with `General` number formatting to the worksheet.

**Bad workaround**

If your situation allows it (i.e. maybe if you only want to reference/display the table's values and not calculate/compute/perform any numerical operations), you could change the percentage values to text. (Not really a solution and a pretty bad workaround as internal representation of values is changed.)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    transformed = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"ID", Text.From, type text}, {"Date", each DateTime.ToText(_, "M/d/yyyy"), type text}, {"Value", Percentage.From, Percentage.Type}}),
    newHeaders = List.Distinct(transformed[Date]),  
    pivoted = Table.Pivot(transformed, newHeaders, "Date", "Value", List.Sum),
    stringifyPercentageColumns = List.Accumulate(newHeaders, pivoted, (tableState, currentHeader) => Table.TransformColumns(tableState, {{currentHeader, each Text.From(_ * 100) & "%", type text}}) )
in
    stringifyPercentageColumns
```

**Okay workaround**

As you've mentioned, applying number formatting via VBA might be necessary. `QueryTable.AfterRefresh` event seems more relevant ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.afterrefresh) and [worked example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136069/)) but requires a lot of setup code for such a simple task; so `Worksheet_Change` event might be quicker to set up.

Maybe somebody else can give you an actual solution, but I think the problem is with Excel not having a "default number format" (if such a concept even exists) for Power Query's `Percentage` type. So the problem isn't with Power Query but with Excel, but I'm just guessing and could be wrong.

---

Unrelated. Your `M` code seems to include three separate `Table.TransformColumnTypes`, but I think you only need one (see `transformed` expression in my `M` code).

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. So far it seems that a VBA solution is inevitable. Unfortunate that this cannot all be done without VBA.  And, as you surmise, text representations of percentage is not really acceptable.  so far as the multiple `Table.TransformColumnTypes`, I'm pretty inexperienced with PQ. The code was generated by the UI and, since it demonstrated the point I was trying to make, I didn't try to clean it up.